# Understanding SQL Server Int Data Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, int

I have a table with a column called `PtObjId` of the `INT` data type.

From my understanding by looking at the thread located [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) here. I can only store up to values that are +/- 2,147,483,647

If I run this query:

```
Select top 100 *
from [table]
where [PtObjId] IN (44237141916)
```

Shouldn't it error out?

Why does this query error out below:

```
select top 100 *
from [table]
where [PtObjID] IN ('44237141916')
```

but the top query doesn't error out?

Comment: Probably implicit cast. You probably you get `where cast([PtObjId] as bigint) IN (44237141916)`.

Comment: I wouldn't expect "where integer in string literal" to execute at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [sqlshack-article](https://www.sqlshack.com/implicit-conversion-in-sql-server/)  explains details about implicit conversions in SQL-Server.

One value must implicitly be cast for the comparison. The literal `44237141916` is treated as `decimal`, which has a higher precedence than `int`, so the other operand is cast to `decimal`.

A full list of precedences (and a table of possible conversions) are given in the article, an extract:

```
10. float
11. real
12. decimal
13. money
14. smallmoney
15. bigint
16. int
17. smallint
18. tinyint 
...
25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max))
```

<sup>(lower number = higher precedence)</sup>

In the case of `int` and `nvarchar`, the one with higher precedence is `int`, and this leads to an overflow for 44237141916.

Comment: The literal `44237141916` is treated as `decimal` not `bigint` - this is for backwards compatibility reasons as the behaviour existed before `bigint` datatype was in the product

Comment: Ah interesting, I've changed that.